# Postal Address field inline items output

Tags: theming, entities

I have a postal address field which I display with an icon in front of it. I have a field template file which is as follows:

```
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
   <div class="field-items"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
     <?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item): ?>
       <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></div>
       <div class="field-item <?php print $delta % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?>"<?php print $item_attributes[$delta]; ?>><?php print render($item); ?></div>
       <div class="clear"></div>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

The rendered item displays the different elements of the postal address on separate lines (Company name, thoroughfare, post code,...). I essentially want to put all these elements inline. But I cannot find how to do that... 
Any suggestions?

Comment: You'd have to refer directly to the item by key instead of loop over `$items`. For example, `render($items['postal_code'])`. I don't know the exact names of the items, so you would need xdebug or devel to look that up.

Comment: It didn't quite work. I suspect the complexity of that field and my knowledge are both the cause of my failure with your method. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to access the content of the addressfield. Instead of `<?php print render($item); ?>`, I do this:

```
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <div class="field-items"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
   <?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item): ?>
    <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></div>
    <div class="field-item <?php print $delta % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?>"<?php print $item_attributes[$delta]; ?>>

            <?php if(!empty($element['#object']->field_where_location["und"][0]["organisation_name"])): ?>
              <?php print $element['#object']->field_where_location["und"][0]["organisation_name"]; ?>,
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if(!empty($element['#object']->field_where_location["und"][0]["thoroughfare"])): ?>
              <?php print $element['#object']->field_where_location["und"][0]["thoroughfare"]; ?>,
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if(!empty($element['#object']->field_where_location["und"][0]["locality"])): ?>
              <?php print $element['#object']->field_where_location["und"][0]["locality"]; ?>,
            <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
</div>
```

The `$element['#object']` is used as if it was $node variable. I just had to read the template instructions a bit better!

Comment: Right, you wouldn't need the loop.. one thing to note is since you are not using `render`, the fields never pass access checks. May apply here may not, but best practice is always pipe through the rendering layer.